# get Index exceeds matrix dimensions error when implement fileparts function without loop

Tags: matlab, matrix

Sorry if the title is a bit not clear. I have a code to read a bounch of fas files and then use the 
for loop and the fileparts function call to extract the corresponding parts

```
[pathstr, name, ext] = fileparts(files(i).name)
```

It works well when I put the fileparts function call inside of a for loop while it gives me an index exceeds matrix dimensions error without the for loop. Does anyone understand why? Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Edit: outside of the loop, the code is like 
[pathstr, name, ext] = fileparts (files(1).name)

Comment: How do you use it outside the loop? Are you using the same code you have shown? What is i outside loop?

Comment: On its own, that code looks plausible. Please post a simple reproduction that we can run that demonstrates the problem. I tried your code like so: `files = dir(); for i = 1:numel(files), [pathstr, name, ext] = fileparts(files(i).name); end` and it worked fine.

Comment: Could you add the full error message to your question?